# Infinite list of variables which average each other

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots$ be a sequence of positive real numbers.

Suppose that each $x_n$ can be written as an average of all the numbers in the list: for each $n$ there are $w_{n;i}>0$ for $i\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}w_{n;i}=1$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}w_{n;i}x_i=x_n$$
Can we prove that all $x_n$ are the same value?

Comment: What does $w_{ni}$ mean? Is $ni$ a product of two indices? Thus do we draw from the same sequence? Or; is it $w_{n;i}$ meaning, thus we employ a different sequence for each $n$?

Comment: I meant different indices. I will edit the question

Comment: If there is such a non-constant sequence, it can't have a maximum term, nor a minimum, but I suppose something like $.5,.1,.9,.01,.99,.001,.999,\dots$ might work.

Comment: Maybe $1/2,3/4,1/4,7/8,5/8,3/8,1/8,15/16\dots$.

Comment: Much more generally, fix $x_1, x_2, \ldots \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and define
$$D = \{w \in \ell^1(\mathbb{R}) \mid \forall i, w_i > 0; \;\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i = 1; \;\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_ix_i \text{ exists} \}.$$

Then the image of the map $\varphi : D \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\varphi(w) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_ix_i$ is the interior of the convex hull of $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ where the interior is determined in the affine space generated by $x_1, x_2, \ldots$

Comment: I think for any sequence that never attains a minimum or maximum (bounded or not), we can always find such $w_{n;i}$.